# How to make Fn + Up/Down arrows perform PgUp/PgDn in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

My time using a Mac has made me develop the muscle memory of doing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to do <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>. Is there a good way to enable this behavior in Windows?